# Shortest representation of this function in Python

Tags: python, math

[image: equation]

Currently I have:

```
def func(points): #Input is a matrix with n lines and 2 columns.
    centroid = numpy.mean(points, axis=0)
    sum = 0
    for point in points:
        x = point[0] - centroid[0]
        y = point[1] - centorid[1]
        sum += x**2 + y**2
    return math.sqrt(sum)
```

Comment: Your code accumulates `x**2 + y**2`, then takes the square root.  But your formula accumulates the square root of `x**2 + y**2`.

Comment: You have a typo in line 6: wrongly centorid, instead of centroid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a builtin for summation of a sequence, called `sum` (oddly enough). We can create the data using a generator comprehension, and feed it directly to the `sum` function. Thus:

```
return math.sqrt(sum((p[0]-centroid[0])**2 + (p[1]-centroid[1])**2 for p in points))
```

Comment: Replying to a deleted comment: Strongly disagree that putting a formula on multiple lines makes it more readable, especially a fairly simple and common one like this (adding in quadrature). Comprehensions are fundamental to Python, and building a list yourself in simple situations is ugly and furthermore contradicts "there should only be one way to do it". What do you propose to call the sub-expressions, anyway? `sum` masks a builtin, and is far from descriptive anyway.

Comment: agreed. Frankly, when a formula gets split into steps it makes much less sense and it's harder to recognize it for what it is.

Comment: Nice, the only thing I might do slightly different.
mx, my = numpy.mean(points, axis=0);
return math.sqrt(sum((x-mx)**2 + (y-my)**2 for x, y in points))

Comment: @mrtw I followed the code, not the formula image. +1 for pointing it out; I'm sure the OP can figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using NumPy, you can use [`numpy.hypot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hypot.html):

```
def func(points):
    centroid = np.mean(points, axis=0)
    return np.sum(np.hypot(points[:,0]-centroid[0], points[:,1]-centroid[1]))
```

I believe, though am not sure, that indexing using the numpy [:,n] syntax is faster than a list comprehension.  Similarly, using `np.sum` should be faster than using Python's `sum`.

NOTE: `hypot` calculates the square root, thus moving the square root inside the sum.  This reflects the equation in your question, although your code does something different.